# ElasticSearch compound queries

Tags: elasticsearch

My index data is

```json
    {
      "first_name":"Kevin",
      "last_name":"John",
      "job": "IT"
    }
    {
      "first_name":"John",
      "last_name":"Thimothy",
      "job": "Accountant"
    }
    {
      "first_name":"Eric",
      "last_name":"Villa",
      "job": "Driver"
    }
    {
      "first_name":"John",
      "last_name":"Villa",
      "job": "Student"
    }
```

I am not sure if anyone could help me to build a query to get data that have `first_name` or `last_name` as `John` and have a job as `IT` or `Student`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a combination of the [`bool/must/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query) clause

**Search Query:**

```json
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "first_name": "John"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "last_name": "John"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "job": "IT"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "job": "student"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Search Result will be

```json
    "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "66982646",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 2.4079456,
            "_source": {
              "first_name": "Kevin",
              "last_name": "John",
              "job": "IT"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "66982646",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 1.89712,
            "_source": {
              "first_name": "John",
              "last_name": "Villa",
              "job": "Student"
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: That saves my day as I don't know if we can use a combination of the bool/must/should clause. Thank you